# I am not sure what is blocking this test case, currently it goes into infinite loop

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I need to run this test case but currently it gets stuck in an infinite loop. This is the minimalistic code, Any suggestion is appreciated.

Test.tsx file:

```
it('verify useDeleteExclusions', async () => {
    deleteExclusionDevices.mockResolvedValue([])
    const {result} = renderHook(() => useDeleteExclusions(['1234']), {
      wrapper: AllTheProviders,
    })

    act(() => {})
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(result.current).toEqual({"errorExclusionIds": [], "loading": false, "successExclusionIds": []})
    })
  })

})
```

Hook that needs to be tested:

```
export function useDeleteExclusions(exclusionIds) {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState<any>([])
  useEffect(() => {
    async function deleteExclusionDevicesAsync(exclusionIds) {
      const res = await deleteExclusionDevices(exclusionIds)
    }
    deleteExclusionDevicesAsync(exclusionIds)
  }, [exclusionIds])

  return { response }
}
```

Api call function (used by hook):

```
export async function deleteExclusionDevices(exclusionIds: any): Promise<any> {
  const token = await readToken()
  const response = []
  return response
}
```

Test gets stuck like this:
[image]

Comment: It seems like your `expect(...).equal(...)` never meets its conditions, causing `waitFor` to wait forever. I'd say add a timeout to make the test fail during loops. You'll probably have to manually debug to figure out why the conditions aren't met. E.g. I don't see you using `setResponse` anywhere.

Comment: Hi @KelvinSchoofs this is minimalistic code that's why `setResponse` is not being used. Thanks for hint.